# How to search a tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I search a specific tag with TortoiseSVN?

Thanks.

Comment: In which language, which platform...?
Can you state your question a little bit more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go to "repobrowser" and use "showlog" on your "tags" folder (or on whole project)

Then type your tagname into the search field on top of the log-dialog.

You can also search by yourself in repobrowser browsing your "tags" folder.

What are your difficulties exactly?

Comment: No wonder I cannot find. I don't have permission to see the tags folder